# Joining two dataframes using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I'm trying to join 2 data frames using regex. In one data frame is Postcode Area (e.g. BA, M) in the other is Postcode District (e.g. BA1, M18). I want to join on the Postcode Area. My regex is ([A-Z][A-Z]?). How to I actually join the two data frames on this regex?

My regex is ([A-Z][A-Z]?).

Comment: [How to merge pandas table by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522818/how-to-merge-pandas-table-by-regex)

Comment: I don’t understand - I have a set regex to be applied as the join condition. The circumstances in that post seem very different with 3 different regex functions stored within the data frame to perform the join on

Comment: Hi Oscar! Welcome to StackOverflow. I think it's best to do the matches beforehand and then join

Comment: From the wiki of the pandas tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "PostcodeArea" : ["BA", "M", "AB"],
        "Location" : ["Bath", "Manchester", "Aberdeen"],

    }
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "PostcodeDistrict" : ["BA1", "M1", "AB1"],
    }
)

df2.assign(PostcodeArea = df2['PostcodeDistrict'].str.extract(r"([A-Z]+)")).merge(df1, on="PostcodeArea")

# Output:
  PostcodeDistrict PostcodeArea    Location
0              BA1           BA        Bath
1               M1            M  Manchester
2              AB1           AB    Aberdeen
```